# Trying to understand the following generator in python

Tags: python-3.x, generator

I am trying to understand the difference between the following two code snippets. The second one just prints the generator but the first snippet expands it and iters the generator. Why does it happen? 
Is it because the two square brackets expand any iterable object?

---

```
#Code snippet 1


li=[[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[7,8,9]] 
for col in range(0,3):
    print( [row[col] for row in li] )`
Output: 
[1, 4, 7]
[2, 5, 8]
[3, 6, 9]
```

---

```
#Code snippet 2


li=[[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[7,8,9]]
for col in range(0,3):
    print( row[col] for row in li )
```

> Output

```
<generator object <genexpr> at 0x7f1e0aef55c8>
<generator object <genexpr> at 0x7f1e0aef55c8>
<generator object <genexpr> at 0x7f1e0aef55c8>
```

---

Why is the output of above two quotes different?

Comment: This first one is called a list comprehension and is producing a list, and that is what is printed. The second one is actually printing the "object" that is generating the list.

Comment: What do you mean by a list comprehension? I am trying to understand why it is expanded unlike the second snippet.

Comment: Search the web for "python3 list comprehension tutorial".

Comment: Read it, thanks. So is it just a format where list comprehension will expand the iterable object into the corresponding items?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `print` function outputs the returning values of the `__str__` method of the objects in its arguments. For lists, the `__str__` method returns a nicely formatted string of comma-delimited item values enclosed in square brackets, but for generator objects, the `__str__` method simply returns generic object information so to avoid altering the state of the generator.

By putting a generator expression in square brackets you're using list comprehension to explicitly make a list by iterating through the output of the generator expression. Since the items are already produced, the `__str__` method of the list would have no problem returning their values.

Comment: Thank you, I understand it now. So if the __str__ method will try to access the iterables it might change the state but if it accesses the list iterable it cannot change it?

Comment: Yes, because all the items in the list are already produced, as opposed to generators, in which items have yet to be produced.

Comment: Ah okay.Thanks a ton:)